# How to embed Stack Overflow flair in a WordPress.com (free) blog?

Tags: discussion, flair

Has anyone successfully embedded their [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) on a WordPress.com-hosted blog?

The free hosted version of [WordPress.com](http://www.WordPress.com) (not [WordPress.org](http://www.WordPress.org)) [strips out all unwanted code](http://support.wordpress.com/code/) from all posts before publishing. So they to strip out just about anything I can add to embed my Stack Overflow flair.

*Note: I'll be switching to a paid, hosted site in the future (fixing the problem), but I'm looking for a quick, short-term solution.*

Comment: sounds like this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image is what you need

Comment: Yes. If that feature is implemented it would definitely be a solution here.

Comment: Another way is using text widget to embed the flair as a custom menu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the list of permissible tags shown by WordPress.Org, there doesn't seem to be an easy way.

But, if (hint, hint) PNG was one of the supported formats for flair, you'd be *in*.

Comment: Okay, Bevan... Spill it. Is there some "service" out there that periodically creates a PNG out of my flair which I can then link to directly? Short of that, I'm not good at (hint, hint) <grin>.

Comment: Sorry, no, there's no service that I know of ... I was kinda trying to hint to our benevolent overlord (Jeff), who's participating in this question, that this would be a useful extension to the flair system.

Comment: Question #1475 (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image) is related.

Answer (score 7):

The new flair is built with using a PNG image, so cheers!
Now you can have your Stack Overflow flair on WordPress!

Check out the Stack Overflow blog entry "[Flair: Now Even Flairier](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/)".

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to your user profile on any Stack Exchange site
2. Click Flair
3. Copy the HTML from the appropriate box. (to change the theme, add `?theme=clean` or `?theme=dark` or `?theme=hotdog` to the end of the image URL)
4. Go to the Customize page of your Wordpress.com site.
5. Select Widgets
6. Add a Text widget
7. Paste the HTML into the box and (optionally) create a title for the widget
8. Save it.

You now have your Stack Flair on your Wordpress blog.

Comment: You nailed it, this should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Not the official flair, but this unofficial one by Steven Robbins should work:

[Updated: Stack Overflow Wordpress Widget](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/07/09/updated-stack-overflow-wordpress-widget/)

Comment: Very nice. But I'm 99 and 44/100% certain that Wordpress.com (not .org) will strip out all that code and it won't work. They are are very strict about filtering out just about everything to do anything: http://support.wordpress.com/code/ . Do you know different?

Comment: Maybe ask Steven ;-p

Comment: Have you tried it? If you are allowed widgets then it should work. It only emits some divs, an image and a bit of styling - it doesn't need embed, frame, iframe, form, input, object, textarea etc.

Comment: The problem is you can't install any additional plugins into a wordpress.com blog.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc mentioned, you should be able to use the Wordpress widget (assuming you can use widgets), or failing that you can use the Flair as a PNG thing I threw together this afternoon. I've posted more details on the [Can we get flair as an image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image/4525#4525) question.

Comment: This is a nice workaround for SO not directly supporting images, as Ohloh does.