# Can we get flair as an image?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flair

Currently, you can get flair as HTML, Javascript, or JSON.  Let's say I'm extra-cautious of XSS vulnerabilities.  In that case the HTML and Javascript options are a no-no for me.  JSON is possible if I use a trusted parser, but it's still just basically giving me HTML stored in a JS variable.  A better option for me is a dynamically-generated image.  You could cache the generated image for some time (say, 30 minutes?) to cut down on server demand.

**Update**: As pointed out by [Kyle Cronin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/658/kyle-cronin) and [rcar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/rcar) (see also [meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1238/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/how-to-embed-stackoverflow-flair-in-a-wordpress-com-free-blog)), a much greater need for this feature would be for use in sites which disallow iframes and scripting, for example when used as a sig on a forum, or when used on a blog hosted by wordpress.com.

Related: [Offer additional properties to JSON flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/offer-additional-properties-to-json-flair)

Comment: The only potential problem that I would bring up is the ability to "skin" the theme of the flair. However, if that can be overcome somehow, this might work nicely.

Comment: the desired "skin" could still be passed in via query string, like parameters for size of a gravatar image

Comment: What does status-deferred mean? It's not declined, nor accepted. Is it in limbo somewhere?

Comment: *defer* : postpone, hold back to a later time

Comment: Related: [Flair as Images: ASP MVC Style](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37651/flair-as-images-asp-mvc-style)

Comment: @Somnath: see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/) (linked to from the now-top-voted answer - sorry Steven!)

Comment: Yes, we have that now, but [**not without the cookie!**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310554/223701)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Now possible:

```
http://SITE.stackexchange.com/users/flair/YOUR-USER-ID.png
```

More details [in the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/). Note that the network flair only shows accounts that have > 200 rep.

Comment: for SOFU one still needs the old URLs, right? Like http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/89334.png rather than http://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com/users/flair/89334.png (though that image is lovely too!)

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to this, it would also allow the image to still work when SO is down for maintenance because the server serving the images could be entirely separate (and lightweight). I'd really like to see this too.

Comment: It would also reduce the need to have a time based image cache strategy.

Comment: @brad: i think the time-based cache would still be a good idea... the code to generate an image (including fetching the gravatar image) is going to be several orders of magnitude slower than just reading a cached image.  imagine if i include my flair image on a super popular site, then SO would have to generate the image millions of times at once.  of course, maybe the overhead is low enough that this is still feasible... i'm just saying if i were designing it i'd use a time-based cache (and i was trying to head off potential excuses not to do this)

Comment: Image based flair shouldn't need to be cached less 64 hours. Seriously though, who needs his flair to be updated more than once a day or so? That would be very lightweight on the server.

Answer (score 4):

## Image Based Flair

I have created an implementation of flair which generates an image of your current reputation automatically. It is currently using PHP GD.

> [More Information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9482/image-based-flair-downloadable-implementation-v2-1)

---

### Current Features

**Configurable**
Edit your accounts by opening `system/config.yaml` and editing the values.

**Customizable**
Create your own themes by editing/adding YAML files. (2 themes by default [basic,advanced] in 2 different flavors [normal, inverted])

**Expandable**
Currently supports all 4 SO sites. Adapts to new additions to the StackOverflow family with a simple config file.

---

### Examples

**This script no longer works due to the new flair API. I have no intention of updating it.**

<sub>The desktop theme included in the distribution will not render exactly the same as the above. The reason is that I didn't include one font used due to licensing restrictions. For reference, the reputation font (missing) is **DIN 1451 Engschrift LT**. The theme files are as in, so by dropping in the font as `dinb.ttf` in the `system/fonts` folder, it should render as the above.</sub>

Comment: I really like the advanced light and advanced dark.

Comment: The images show PHP errors, like: http://alpha.wolfmicrosystems.com/flair/basic/StackOverflow.png

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [StackImage](https://stackapps.com/questions/847/stackimage-generating-images-of-questions-and-users)?

It does exactly that.

http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/flair.php?id=142114&site=meta
http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/flair.php?id=142114&site=meta&border=ffffff&background=3b5998&text=ffffff&title=dddddd&font1=serif&font2=serifitalic

It is highly customizable and also has smart caching to prevent excessive load on my server.

Answer (score 0):

It would also be nice to be able to retrieve flair data as XML. It would make it easier to customize the way it's displayed, using XSL for instance.

Comment: unlikely, since JSON is so much more web-friendly

Comment: Yes, but it's not as easy as XML to read from C#... come on Jeff, it can't take you more that 10 minutes ;)

Comment: Two comments: @Jeff, wake up but not the whole world is web (or even web-friendly). @Thomas, wasn't there a JSON reader/writer in the .NET framework already?

Comment: @peSHIr: yes, I think there is... but I like XML, and anyway I don't like the idea of using a Javascript format in C# ;)