# Making the Flair API more usable for further processing

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flair, http

I want to build a little php script to process my flair requested as json, to get a nice image to use on boards and such.
For the sake of the server, I want to cache it.

The best way of doing this should be by using [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag). If this would be supported I could simply save the latest ETag and send it with every request. If the server returns 200 Ok the script would process the returned json to for example a new image.

So, would it be possible to add this feature.

Comment: if you add the "feature" tag this may get noticed quicker.

Comment: Done that. Hope a answer will pop up.

Comment: you might find that the json is lacking.  see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/offer-additional-properties-to-json-flair

Comment: also, this suggestion might be unnecessary if the following were implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image

Comment: Hm, yeah. But it are different things... images are too much a style thing, and very server intensive. If they implemented both this and the json updates...

Comment: Have to say, this has been in status=review for a long time, how long does that usually take?

Comment: It does take very long. How long does status-review take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've deprecated the JSON and IFRAME flairs in favor of the simpler .png image flairs:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/

Can you switch to that?

Comment: Perfect, seen it before, but forgot about the question I asked.