# How can i link my UserProfile on my personal homepage?

Tags: support, status-completed, api, profile-page

I want to put a link to my SO profile on my homepage. I remember a codesnippet i saw somewhere that would basically display my Username and my reputation. Where was that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean the [flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair) tool?

Answer (score 3):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/nowearn-valuable-flair

and

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Answer (score 0):

Also, to get flair as an image: [Can we get flair as an image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image/4525#4525)