# How to add flair to email signature?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, email, flair

Random question, but is there a way to add your flair to an email signature?

**UPDATE**
So  the consensus is not to do it. Admins/Moderators, please feel free to close this question.

Comment: It's lame on email. Don't do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See: [Can we get flair as an image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image)

That said, big fat sigs with images and lots of irrelevant information are ugly and somewhat rude. Don't do it.

Comment: +1 for being ugly and rude.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it's proper to do this (hey, Joel Spolsky does it, for the record) it is now possible with flair available as a simple png image:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/