# What is the total number of hits/day for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics, traffic

As Stack Overflow grows day by day and a larger number of people use it daily, what is the total number of hits/day for Stack Overflow?

Comment: See the graphs on this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26689/how-do-we-grow-the-server-fault-and-super-user-communities

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can see the daily figures [at Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com). By default it shows people, click on the Page-Views option in the combo box to see the views.

Currently it is getting around 1.4-1.5M/day on weekdays and around 0.6M/day at weekends.

[image: Quantcast graph]

Comment: Stackoverflow has a quantcast tracking pixel on each page, so these numbers are accurate.  Just want to make sure people don't compare these to alexa or other services that merely estimate such data.

Comment: This link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jeff mentioned it was currently at around 1.4m hits a day in [Podcast #81](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/podcast-81/), so that figure's probably accurate to around Jan 31st, 2010.