# Up to date page views of Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the total number of hits/day for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38263/what-is-the-total-number-of-hits-day-for-stack-overflow)

Is there an official source to get up to date page view numbers of Stack Overflow?

The lastest information I found is 95 million page views a month. Is it even possible to get it more detailed, like *xxx requests or page views per seconds*?

I want to use Stack Overflow for a case study about web server loads. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could probably do something with the [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). For example, here's one that you could use to determine the views between certain post IDs:
[total post view count](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73509/total-page-view-count)

Comment: you are right! It is a duplicate. I got my answer. Thanks.