# Flair profile badge in forum signature?

Tags: discussion, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get flair as an image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image)

Is it possible to add my profile flair badge to a forum signature?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image