# Flair as Images: ASP MVC Style

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flair

## Flair as Images

I know, this has been done before.

However, In hopes that we can have this done on a non-hack basis, I have created an implementation that works on **ALL STACK EXCHANGE SITES**.

Jeff, et al: please consider using this implementation!  I would really like an official version.

[Jeff Atwood http://otac0n.com/StackOverflow/flair/1.png?theme=dark](http://otac0n.com/StackOverflow/flair/1.png?theme=dark)

http://files.otac0n.com/StackOverflowFlair.zip

## EDIT:

Woooo hooo!  Completed!  Thanks, team.

### I have set up a permanent redirect from my site to StackOverflow.com

That means, that everyone using mine should now be using yours automatically, for the main site.  It will break for other sites, tho.

Everyone, please update your image links.

#### Can I get a status-completed flag?  Please?

Comment: @Robert you use it by embedding the suggested URL format in an img element on your page. John provides an example in his post or you can check the source of the various images. As an aside I think this is a great suggestion!

Comment: I hadn't noticed my flair was !@#& but thanks, I'll fix it :-)

Comment: OK, fixed.  Flair wasn't working in the StackExchange beta when I first set that up, and I didn't go back to check in the next version.  BTW, thanks for including me on the list above ;-)

Comment: BTW, looks like the image version above is cached for some amount of time.  The real link to the right should show correct if you reload with cache bypass.

Comment: @BasicallyMoney.com:  I can see that it is fixed now, but it may take a while for my caches to expire.

Comment: Can we get the source code? The link given below does not work.

Comment: @Immortal: http://files.otac0n.com/StackOverflowFlair.zip  Sorry, my link was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Anti-aliasing please:

```
graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit; 
// or TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
```

Comment: That has been done from the beginning.  However, this is running on a virtual IIS server.

Comment: Also, if you zoom in, you can see that it is antialiasing.  You are asking for "Clear Type", which I can't seem to get GDI+ to do.

Comment: @John: try setting the rendering hint explicitly (see my edit)

Comment: Did that too.  It all looks great on my dev machine, and all. However, on the server, antialiasing and Unicode are broke.

Comment: @John: Sounds like a good Stack Overflow question!

Comment: I'm sure it just has to do with Windows Server's support of ClearType and the fonts that are installd on the box...

Comment: Does that look better?

Comment: @John: I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

The Flair-as-Image looks good but my gold badge doesn't appear in your version. See below:

Screen capture from Stack Overflow vs. "Flair as Images: ASP MVC Style":

[image]

Below is the actual linked-png for a "live" comparison to see if it is fixed:

[alt text http://otac0n.com/StackOverflow/flair/98786.png?site=stackoverflow.com&theme=default](http://otac0n.com/StackOverflow/flair/98786.png?site=stackoverflow.com&theme=default)

Comment: AH!  `\d+ gold badges` will not match `1 gold badge`. I will fix  it when I get home.

Comment: Actually: Done, I fixed that from here.

Comment: surely the simplest solution would have been for you to get another gold badge?

Comment: @home4film.com - Curse my lazy fingers. I'm off to ask a "Famous Question" which will quickly gather 10,000 views. Be back in 5.

Comment: That's the spirit

Answer (score 0):

http://otac0n.com/StackOverflow/flair/2.png?site=forceclose.com
This is really good. I would really like the source code so I could integrate this into [Force Close](http://forceclose.com) (my StackExchange site). Is there any way I can obtain it?

Comment: Yeah, I have it hosted at http://files.otacon.com/StackOverflowFlair.zip  However, I'm  currently trying to get Jeff to add it to the base product.

Comment: Sorry, that's http://files.otac0n.com/StackOverflowFlair.zip