# Can we get a flair image with a transparent background?

Tags: feature-request, flair

Following up from *[Can we get flair as an image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/155837)*, none of the available flair images are a good match for my blog’s theme.  “Clean” comes closest, but the white background is wrong for me.

Can we please get a flair theme with a transparent background?

Comment: If we still supported HTML based flair we could have allowed users to edit basic CSS values...

Comment: +1 I can see no reason why this couldn't be done with current png flairs. A pair of images with transparent backgrounds and dark/bright fonts would make the flairs much easier to match to a website.

Comment: Frankly, this depends a lot on Gravatar. It [looks lie they support it](http://blog.gravatar.com/2008/06/06/image-transparency-you-want-it-you-got-it/), though.

Comment: @DJDavid98 you can add new answer with the image as suggested mock-up. As an edit, it's incorrect.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi, see my profile image above: Gravatar definitely supports transparency.

Comment: Can we just get a better looking flair image period...

Comment: This post was last active 2 years, is there any progress on this?