# How many points do I need for the community icons appear on my Flair?

Tags: discussion, flair, network-profile, combined-flair

So, I have a few accounts on the Stack Exchange Network, and most of them are around 100 points. I've recently added the Network Flair to my profile, but it's only showing the Stack Overflow icon; other communities do not appear. I'm wondering if this is either a bug or it's based on a number of points for the icons to appear on the Network Flair.

How many points do I need for an icon appear to appear on the flair?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image/65224?s=3|0.0000#65224 Is just one of the many instances where you would've seen the answer for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 200 rep for an icon to appear on the combined flair.

Quoting the page where you can find the flair:

> please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours

Comment: Thanks @ProgramFOX =)