# Can I have my flair without the cookie, please?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flair, cookies, gdpr

Even though I would like so, I refrain from adding a flair link on my personal web site because solely serving [the PNG flair image file](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2403292.png)
 already places a third party `prov` cookie on the computer of my web site visitors. (I added my flair here without any link for easy testing purposes.)

[image: flair]

I really cannot see the necessity for this `prov` cookie which expires only on `Fri 01 Jan 2055 01:00:00 CET`.
Moreover, **as a personal web site owner it burdens me with an additional legal liability to comply with EU cookie legislation.**

Can I have my flair without the cookie, please?

Comment: I tried to load it into an iframe and sandbox it, but X-Frame-Options stops that from working

Comment: If your host provides a service like netlify's proxying, you may be able to relay the request, and strip out the cookie automatically (https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#proxying)

Comment: Potentially interesting question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310822/is-embedding-arbitrary-external-images-gdpr-compliant

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for the request, Serge. This is implemented (or de-implemented I guess?) now. It wasn't our intention to bake a `prov` cookie on this route so we won't anymore. This should be fixed for both network and site specific flair.

Comment: One of those small changes with big impact. Thanks!!