# Creating Wikipedia User boxes for Stack Exchange Websites

Tags: discussion, wikipedia, integration

Wikipedia has a feature called [Userboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Userboxes) which are used in user pages on it to provide stylized information about the user. There are many many types of userboxes, describing interests, achievements, skills, etc. One example of such userbox is the "{{Template:User github}}" userbox, which Wikipedia users who are also active GitHub users often place in their profile.

However, there are no userboxes at all regarding Stack Exchange websites. Since both Wikipedia and Stack Exchange are places where people help contribute and distribute knowledge, I think it would be a nice addition to create a series of such user boxes for Wikipedia users who are also active Stack Exchange members to place on their profile.

However, I don't really have proper design skills, and I don't know if I would even be allowed to use Stack Exchange logos when making them.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: We do have [flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image) to show on other sites (that only shows reputation and badges). Unless you mean you want to show Wikipedia boxes on your Stack Exchange profile, in which case you can do that as is - in the worst case you'll need to make it an image. Unless you mean something closer to [usercards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), which is your Stack Exchange profile displayed on Stack Exchange.

Comment: This might be useful in creating a box. However, it seems like most boxes are designed not to give away too much personal information, and we might want one which isn't specifically linked to a stack exchange account, but rather displays a more general message like "This user is an active contributor on StackOverflow". That is the case with GitHub's box.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what sort of information you'd like to display on the card. The only information that would really fit there is things specific to Stack Exchange (otherwise you're looking for something which goes well beyond what Stack Exchange does), which is mostly already there. The only thing I might suggest adding is a bigger logo and some selectable tag badges, and maybe a slightly bigger version that actually writes out the name of the site would make sense, not that I ever use the card.

Comment: Are you sure it is not *[userboxen](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22userboxen%22&sa=G&hl=en-DK&gbv=1&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0ahUKEwj24JHXoObdAhXFFiwKHZQ8BVAQsAQIIQ)*?

Comment: The logo would have to be under a free license. Other than that, it's not too hard to piece something together using [Template:Userbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Userbox).