# Flair should look more StackOverflowish

Tags: feature-request, flair

How about making flair look just like our representation on SO and related sites.

I agree totally that [it should be more distinctive about the site name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/flair-should-be-more-distinctive-about-site-name).

And yes, the entire image should be clickable, not just the gravatar and id.

So how about something like this: (With apologies to Jon)

[image]

---

Edit: Okay, okay, so I'm not the best artist. One of you can come up with something better.

But the idea is this: The flair, the way it is now, does not say StackOverflow or indicate what it is. You hover over it, and if you are lucky and hover over the image or id, it might say "see my profile on StackOverflow".

You don't have to like my artwork, but I'd be surprised if noone agrees with the idea.

And did you -1 me because I used a .jpg????  I should flag that comment as hate speech (someone who hates jpegs).

---

[Andrew Moore offers another design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9482/image-based-flair-downloadable-implementation-v2-1) that at least has StackOverflow front and center in it.

Comment: .jpg's in this day and age?!

Comment: That pic's got more artifacts than Indiana Jones...I need to stop drinking and posting.

Comment: The down vote was for the idea in general. I personally like the clean style.

Comment: Fair enough.

Comment: @lkessler The image src is broken

Comment: @Alpine: Sorry, nothing I can do about the image. The author of it, Andrew Moore, took it down. It is also broken on the Andrew Moore other design page that I linked to above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this idea. Certainly the whole "flair" should be click-able. I didn't even notice it wasn't because I am still creating my own [image flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/how-to-embed-stackoverflow-flair-in-a-wordpress-com-free-blog).

But a bit of branding at least to identify what the flair *is* sounds like a great idea. I wouldn't want to turn the flair into a giant monstrosity but a small label of some sort shouldn't be out of the question.

I like @Andrew Moore's design for placement and size of the logo, even if it was used within the *current* flair design.

[alt text http://alpha.wolfmicrosystems.com/flair/advanced-inverted-bg/StackOverflow.png](http://alpha.wolfmicrosystems.com/flair/advanced-inverted-bg/StackOverflow.png)

Comment: Andrew's starts to get a bit messy when you add a name and gravatar, which are at least as important, if not more, than a prominent logo.

Comment: More important. I agree with your priorities. I don't need a *prominent* logo. Just *any* logo. Maybe, since the logo is a static graphic, it could be made available for us to tack onto our own flair. Or maybe it could be an optional parameter to add the logo if we don't mind the bulkier flair.

Answer (score 2):

GAH! Flair should be a quick way to show off your awesomeness. We don't need to make it a monstrosity. There's a lot to be said for keeping it simple...

Comment: It holds no credence (except to feel good about yourself) unless it says who it is who is confirming your awesomeness.

Comment: The icon that's there currently is enough to establish the brand. Those in the know will immediately recognize it. Those not will either click it out of curiosity or not care, anyway.

Comment: The icon is so small, it is hardly distinguishable from the dots that represent the badges. And you have to find the right part of the flair to click on. Most people won't bother.