# How to use stack flair in a WordPress site

Tags: support, stack-exchange, flair

I want to add stack flair in my WordPress site. How can I use that?

My site is http://pratikshya.com.np.

I want to put it in the right column.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Duplicate? - [How to embed Stack Overflow flair in a WordPress.com (free) blog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/how-to-embed-stackoverflow-flair-in-a-wordpress-com-free-blog)

Answer (score 3):

The instructions are on the flair page. Just copy and paste the HTML of your WordPress template.

Flair is a `.png` image now so using it is really straightforward.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

In summary:

`<img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/{userid}.png">`

Comment: A word to the wise... don't use the hot-dog stand theme. I know it's 'colorful', but you will see a drop in visitors.

Comment: @george or you might see a *rise* in visitors that like HOT DOGS!!